# Convert lambda function into pickleable object

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, pickle

Is there a function or class that is able to take lambda function as an argument and return object or function that can be pickled using Pickle?

I am trying to parallelize some code using joblib.Parallel that has a problem with lambda function and turning all lambda functions into named functions makes my code look even worse than it did before.

Answer (score 2):

Note that pickling a function merely pickles *its name* and the *name of the module* where it is defined:

```
In [16]: import pickle

In [19]: def foo(x): return x+1

In [20]: pickle.dumps(foo)
Out[20]: 'c__main__\nfoo\np0\n.'
```

So to pickle a function *you need to give it a name*. Unpickling the function requires importing the module.

If naming all the lambda fuctions "makes the code look worse" then perhaps hide them in a separate module, or perhaps think about how the functions can be generalized so as to reduce their number.

Comment: I am trying to avoid big changes to the code unless absolutely necessary. I find lambda functions quite useful and naming all of them and moving them to different module in my situation seems like a clumsy solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dill` instead of `pickle`, which knows how to serialize a `lambda`, even when used as a default argument in a function or a class.

```
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> def doit(x, y=lambda x:x+1):
...   return y(x)
... 
>>> doit(3)
4
>>> _ = dill.dumps(doit)
>>> _
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x02K\x02K\x02KCU\n|\x01\x00|\x00\x00\x83\x01\x00Sq\x05N\x85q\x06)U\x01xq\x07U\x01yq\x08\x86q\tU\x07<stdin>q\nU\x04doitq\x0bK\x01U\x02\x00\x01q\x0c))tq\rRq\x0ec__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0bh\x00(h\x04(K\x01K\x01K\x02KCU\x08|\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x17Sq\x0fNK\x01\x86q\x10)h\x07\x85q\x11U\x07<stdin>q\x12U\x08<lambda>q\x13K\x01U\x00q\x14))tq\x15Rq\x16c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x13NN}q\x17tq\x18Rq\x19\x85q\x1aN}q\x1btq\x1cRq\x1d.'
>>> didit = dill.loads(_)
>>> didit(3)
4
>>>
```

Note that also nested lambdas and closures work just fine too:

```
>>> f = lambda x: lambda y: x+y
>>> f(1)(2)
3
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(f))(1)(2)
3
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(f(1)))(2)
3
>>>
```

I know there's at least a branch of `joblib` that uses `dill` instead of `pickle`, which is probably why you are asking about `pickle` in the first place.  If you can't find the branch, look for one with `cloudpickle`, which is similar to `dill`, and that might also work.

Comment: I did not realize there was such branch, I will look into that!